# Trying to return log in error message in loginbox without reloding page using laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I am trying to make a loginbox with jquery using the laravel framework. I have rules in Laravel which i want it to follow. here the code for that:

```
    $rules = array(
        'username'    => 'required|alphaNum|min:6|max:16',
        'password' => 'required|alphaNum|min:6'
        );
```

They work fine, and when you fail with your login the following code is run:

```
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('index')
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
```

The problem is that the log in-box pops up when called by pressing a button, which becomes a problem when I redirected to another page, because the error messages are written inside the log in box. This is good, however i cant get the log in box to pop up automatically once redirected, so you have to click the log in button again to see the error message and try again.

Here is the jQuery i use:

```
$(function(){
  $('#loginform').submit(function(e){
    return false;
  });
    $('#modaltrigger').leanModal({ top: 110, overlay: 0.45, closeButton: ".hidemodal" });
});
```

And here is the HTML log in form:

```
<div id="loginmodal" style="display:none;">
    <h1>Logga in</h1>

    {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'login')) }}
    <p>
        {{ $errors->first('username') }}
        {{ $errors->first('password') }}
    </p>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            {{ Form::label('username', 'Username', array('class' => 'label')) }}
            {{ Form::text('username', Input::old('username'), array('placeholder' => 'BTH Akronym',
            'class' => 'textfield',
            'id' => 'login-margin',
            )) 
        }}
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        {{ Form::label('password', 'Password', array('class' => 'label')) }}
        {{ Form::password('password', array('placeholder' => 'Lösenord',
        'class' => 'textfield'
        )) }}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="center">
    {{ Form::submit('Logga in', array('class' => 'login-knapp')) }}
</div>

{{ Form::close() }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but something like this should work for you...

### PHP

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    if(Request::ajax()) {
        return Response::json($validator->getMessages());
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('index')->withErrors($validator)->withInput(Input::except('password'));
    }
}
```

The idea here is if the request is an ajax request, it will just return some json which we will be able to use on the success function of an ajax request on your template.

### jQuery

```
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{ route('ajax.form_submit') }}",
        data: $("#form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.length > 0) {
                console.log(data); // Can set your messages on your modal.
                e.preventDefault(); // Stop the form from submitting.
            }
        }
    });
});
```

If there are any error messages, it will log them to the console and give you a good idea of what else needs to be done.  If there are no error messages, it should just continue on with the form submission.

On `$validator->fails()`, I'd probably put an else on there for a success which would actually log the user in.  This way because the function will run twice if it was a successful attempt (once by ajax, once by the form actually submitting), it wouldn't have to run the validator or check the database again (I'm assuming you already have a filter in place on these so it won't run if the user is logged in).